# Problem of divisors of positive int N with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

It remains a little to finish the task, I will be grateful if you help me.
N - positive integer;
I need to find integers A, B, C and D, such that they are divisors of N and N = A + B + C + D;
If there are several fours of numbers, then it is worth deducing such that their product will be the maximum: `(A*B*C*D)max`.
If there are no such fours of numbers, it is necessary to output '-1'.

I will give my thoughts on solving this problem, perhaps you can suggest a more efficient algorithm:

I understand that the problem can be solved through recursion using a recursive tree.
For example: integer N = 8, then divisors will be {1, 2, 4}, I excluded 8 from here because the second condition about the sum will not be fulfilled. We will collect divisors in the vector until the number of edges in the connectivity component of the graph reaches 3.
First, I will output all possible fours of such numbers in this example.
My code in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(vector <int> div, vector <int> v) {

for(int i = 0; i < div.size(); ++i) {
    v.push_back(div[i]);
    if(v.size() == 4) {
        cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << "\n";
        v.pop_back();
    }
    else {
        solve(div, v);
        v.pop_back();
    }
}


return;
}

int main() {
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);

vector <int> div = {1, 2, 4};
vector <int> v;

solve(div, v);
}
```

My problem is that I can't output the final answer.
Although the functions I update it after I find the new four numbers that match the condition.
And yes, I almost forgot, t is the number of tests for various N.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(int n, vector <int> dv, vector <int> v, int MXN) {

for(int i = 0; i < dv.size(); ++i) {
    v.push_back(dv[i]);
    if(v.size() == 4) {
        if(v[0] + v[1] + v[2] + v[3] == n) {
            MXN = max(MXN, v[0]*v[1]*v[2]*v[3]);
            v.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
    else {
        solve(n, dv, v, MXN);
        v.pop_back();
    }
}


return;
}

int main() {
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);

vector <int> dv, v;
int t, n, MXN = -1;
cin >> t;
while(t--) {
    cin >> n;
    dv.push_back(1);
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i) {
        if(n % i == 0 && n != i*i) {
            dv.push_back(i);
            dv.push_back(n/i);
        }
        if(n % i == 0 && n == i*i) {
            dv.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    solve(n, dv, v, MXN);
    cout << MXN << "\n";
    dv.clear();
    v.clear();
    MXN = -1;
}


}
```

Comment: 1) `void solve(vector <int> div, vector <int> v)` -- Why are you passing vector's by value instead of by reference?  Are you aware of the difference between passing by-value and by-reference?  2) `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);` -- Why is this being done? 
3)  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Why are you using this header, which is not a standard C++ header?

Comment: This kind of code looks like what I would expect from "programmers" who use C++ for competitive coding. Instead of someone who is actually learning how to write C++.  The other option is that your training material is of very low quality or out of date (which by the way is also true for competitive coding sites).

Comment: Where did you learn `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?  If it was a book, burn the book.  If it was a website, block the website in your browser.

Comment: This appears to be a coding puzzle from a web site that targets people who want to learn C++ by telling them that there's a secret shortcut to avoid spending years learning C++ from a good textbook: just throw away those textbooks and do coding puzzles from that web site, repeatedly, to quickly become an instant C++ expert. That is, of course, not true; nobody learns anything from those coding puzzles. They use obscure algorithms and programming tricks. Without knowing the right tricks everyone gets a "wrong answer" or a timeout.

Comment: `int MXN = -1; solve(n, dv, v, MXN); cout << MXN << "\n";` -- This is exactly why you can't learn C++ from competitive coding websites -- what value is `MXN` going to have after you called `solve`?  It is still going to be -1, regardless of what you are doing in `solve`, since `MXN` is passed by value.  Advice -- those "competitive coding" websites are designed for persons who know the computer language they will be using well-enough to **never** make fundamental mistakes like this.  Again, they are not there to teach you the basics of C++.

Comment: I want to thank everyone who wrote a comment about my post. The program started working correctly after I added pointers to variables in the function. Indeed, I should have studied the programming language thoroughly before moving on to competetive programming.